# Loading a file from an SFTP Server and converting it to InputStream with Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have read quite a bit about Apache Camel and I still cannot manage to simply load a file from an sftp-resource and make it into an InputStream to be used by some Java business logic.

I tried to create a POJO consumer:

```
import org.apache.camel.Consume;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MyConsumer {

    private InputStream inputStream;

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return inputStream;
    }

    public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public MyConsumer() {
    }

    @Consume(property="inputStream")
    public void onInputStream(InputStream stream) {
        try {
            System.out.println(stream.read());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but when I run

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RoutesBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void addRoutesToCamelContext(CamelContext camelContext) throws Exception {
            from("sftp://127.0.0.1/sftp?username=user&password=password")
                    .bean(new MyConsumer(), "onInputStream");
        }
    });
    context.start();
    context.stop();
```

nothing happens. I feel like it's probably incredibly obvious to make this work, but I don't seem to be able to figure it out.

The sftp server works.

Comment: do u have a ftp server running on your local machine i.e. 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I do and I have checked it's availability and that the credentials are correct.

Comment: You need to keep the JVM/Camel running. What you do is to start and stop it ASAP. See the javadoc on the start method, and this link: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: Your problem most likely is that your context starts and stops immediately. You need to keep your Camel context long running or run for ever. See here http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: A better approach is to develop your Camel app using one of the provided Maven archetypes. That way, all the startup stuff is included by default.